# Learning Models for Time Series Data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, deep-learning, data-transformation, reinforcement-learning

The Problem I'm trying to solve is predicting the performance of the computer system based on the past data, Data is taken by the system every 5 minutes and it contains tons of useful features to predict the performance. But as I told you it is a time-series data taken for the same set of features over a time interval. So how I can effectively model this situation with a learning model which preserves its "time-series" ness of the data?

note: Accuracy is not so important, I want to model which preserves "time" features. 
Thanks

Comment: Build memory models that might include arima structure and identifiable/latent determinstiic structure like hour-of-the-day , day-of-the-week , day-of-the-month etc.

Comment: But I think arima model alone will not help, it more of prediction problem than forecasting

Comment: your comment confuses me as prediction=forecasting in my book..... I was not suggesting arima alone .. I was suggesting a hybrid model that might include arima and possible deterministic structure that is WTD ... waiting to be discovered .

Comment: Are you dealing with multivariate time-series? Which kind of prediction are you interested in? If you aim at predicting some outcome (e.g.: computer system performance) from past values of some features, well that does sound like (multivariate) forecasting to me. Take a look at [this post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/).

Comment: @fsamu Yeah I'm dealing with multivariate time-series (sorry for not mentioning). I'm interested in predicting the throughput of a computer system, based on the features like system usage, CPU cycles etc. But I don't know about Long short-term memory neural net. Want to have a look, meanwhile do you know any beginner friendly tutorial or notes for LSTM, please share :)

Comment: @IrishStat Sorry for the unmeaningful comment, I totally got it, whether that kind of hybrid models are useful for multivariate time series data because I didn't try any of hybrid model before.

Comment: @user15025 Before going into the details of LSTM, I would recommend giving a look at recurrent neural networks in general. I think you may find [this website](http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-1-introduction-to-rnns/) helpful for this purpose.

Comment: LSTM possibly fits well for your situation. I found [this](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) blogpost really useful for understanding LSTM. It should be a comment rather than answer but I can't comment on this platform yet.